# How to create daily data download limit using Mikrotik router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, hotspot, mikrotik-routeros

I have one Mikrotik Router RB951G.
I have two hotspots set up on these two networks:

1. 192.168.1.0/24
2. 192.168.2.0/24

I also have created two user profiles:

1. Guest
2. Employee

I have configured bandwidth limitation on the guest profile. On the other hand, I want to configure daily data download limitation on the employee profile.

I have run these two scripts to do so, but it seems not working.

- script for limiting data

  ```
  #Set your dowload limit in MegaBYTES!
  :local downloadlimitmb "250"

  ### You will not need to edit anything below this line ###
  :local downloadlimit  [($downloadlimitmb  * 1048576)]
  :local counter
  :local datadown
  :local username
  :local macaddress
  :foreach counter in=[/ip hotspot active find where user~"^[T][-].{17}"] do={
  :set $datadown [/ip hotspot active get $counter bytes-out]
  :if ($datadown>$downloadlimit) do={
  :set $username [/ip hotspot active get $counter user]
  :set $macaddress [/ip hotspot active get $counter mac-address]
  /ip hotspot user remove [/ip hotspot user find where name=$username profile=Employee]
  /ip hotspot user add name=$username limit-bytes-out=$downloadlimit mac-address=$macaddress profile=Employee
  /ip hotspot active remove $counter
  :log info "Force logout on user: $username - Reached download quota"
  }}
  ```
- script for clearing user counters

  ```
  :log info "Checking Users"
  :local counter

  :foreach counter in=[/ip hotspot user find profile="Employee" ] do={
  /ip hotspot user remove $counter
  }
  ```

Finally I have added two schedules:

1. to trigger datalimit and runs every minute.
2. to trigger clearcounter and runs every 24 hours.

   one to run every 24 hours